# Llamar valores de una funcion desde otra

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola queria hacer una consulta, como se hace para llamar valores de una funcion desde otra ? Me refiero a que si tengo una funcion1() con x dato y quiero llamar ese x dato desde otra funcion2() se puede ? Se que existe el metodo global, pero sin usar eso seria posible?

Comment: Supongo que con valores te refieres a variables locales a la función. Pro como lo describes,  es posible que un generador o el uso de una clase y un método de instancia se adapten a lo que buscas, pero sería bueno que adjuntaras un ejemplo real de lo que buscas para poder dar una respuesta más acertada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciones trabajan de forma encapsulada, puedes llamarlas dentro de otras funciones, pero una vez se termine su ejecución, todos sus valores internos se pierden de la memoria. Sin embargo, si necesitas valores de ellas, tendrás que retornarlos (`return`) o asignarlos a una variable global.

Por ejemplo:

```
def hacer_ruido(animal):
    if animal == 'perro':
        ruido1 = 'Guau!'
        ruido2 = 'Grrr!'
    elif animal == 'gato':
        ruido1 = 'Miau!'
        ruido2 = 'Prrr!'
    elif animal == 'pato':
        ruido1 = 'Cuac!';
        ruido2 = 'Zzzz'
    else:
        ruido1 = '[No registrado]'
        ruido2 = '[No registrado]'
    return ruido1, ruido2

def mascota(animal):
    sonidos = hacer_ruido(animal) # se llama la funcion, la cual retorna 2 valores
    print('El {} hace {} y tambien {}'.format(animal, sonidos[0], sonidos[1]))

mascota('gato')
mascota('perro');
```

La función `mascota` llama a la función `hacer_ruido` la cual le devuelve los 2 sonidos que hace el animal

> ```
> El gato hace Miau! y tambien Prrr!
> El perro hace Guau! y tambien Grrr!
> ```

Un caso más complejo, pero mucho más libre y potente en cuando al acceso de los valores de "dentro" de las "funciones" es usando programación orientada a objetos.

```
class mascota:
    def __init__(self, animal):
        self.animal = animal
        self.hacer_ruido() # se manda a ejecutar este metodo

    def hacer_ruido(self):
        if self.animal == 'perro':
            ruido1 = 'Guau!'
            ruido2 = 'Grrr!'
        elif self.animal == 'gato':
            ruido1 = 'Miau!'
            ruido2 = 'Prrr!'
        elif self.animal == 'pato':
            ruido1 = 'Cuac!';
            ruido2 = 'Zzzz'
        else:
            ruido1 = '[No registrado]'
            ruido2 = '[No registrado]'
        self.ruido1, self.ruido2 = ruido1, ruido2

    def imprimir_mensaje(self):
        # Se pueden usar "variables" (atributos) que estan definidos dentro de otros metodos
        print('El {} hace {} y tambien {}'.format(self.animal, self.ruido1, self.ruido2))

mascota('perro').imprimir_mensaje()
mascota('gato').imprimir_mensaje()
```

En este caso, apenas se instancia un objeto, `mascota('algo')`, el método especial (constructor) `__init__` manda a ejecutar automáticamente el método `hacer_ruido()` el cual define 2 atributos, `self.ruido1` y `self.ruido2` dependiendo de lo calculado en los `if-else`.
Finalmente `imprimir_mensaje()` imprime la misma salida que el código anterior, pero esta vez haciendo uso de los atributos ya definidos en la clase.

> ```
> El perro hace Guau! y tambien Grrr!
> El gato hace Miau! y tambien Prrr!
> ```